# Can I specify the default SQL Server with two named instances installed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL 2005 Express installed. I then installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and am running both instances successfully. They are named:

- COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS (2005)
- COMPUTERNAME\INSTALL2 (2008)

I am trying to figure out how to specify the 2008 instance as the default server. I have tried:

- Data Source=.\local; ...
- Data Source=.; ...
- Data Source=localhost; ...
- Data Source=(local); ...
- Data Source=127.0.0.1; ...

Each time there is a connection error stating...

```
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. A 
network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify 
that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow 
remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open 
a connection to SQL Server)
```

I have other developers who are working on the same project and only have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and they are able to use `Data Source=(local); ...` to connect without any issues.

Is there a way for me to define my 2008 instance as the default or local instance?

Comment: Why did you install them both as named instances? You could have installed the 2nd one as a defualt instance

Comment: Didn't think about it at the time. Hind sight is 20/20.

Comment: Why don't you just install another instance as Default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Connection Alias](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/01/07/connection-alias.aspx).
See [How to: Create a Server Alias for Use by a Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't choose "default instance" when you installed SQL Server, there's no way to change it after the fact without an uninstall/reinstall. You'll need to fully specify the instance name in your connection string.

```
Data Source=COMPUTERNAME\INSTALL2;
```

Comment: Right. I know that I can connect to mine using COMPUTERNAME\INSTALL2 but was hoping to find a way to define the default instance without reinstalling. This way we can share the same config files for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question and the suggestion of an alias was great as that is exactly what I tried to do.

However my server only two instances velociraptor\sql08R2 and velociraptor\sqlexpress and no default instance.

Connection strings with . or localhost or (local) would fail and if I changed the source code to my machine would break other devs local instances if checked in change.

So came up with better option to change the named pipe for the instance so that it would respond to the localhost options.

Changing the Pipe Name for the instance to "\.\pipe\sql\query"

You can find that setting by starting SQL Server Configuration Manager, and navigating to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for (Instance Name) and right-clicking on Named Pipes and selecting Properties.

[image: PipeName]